# Scalogram on Matlab and Python

Tags: python, matlab, conv-neural-network

I've been trying to plot scalogram on Python with pywt, but my results has no similarity with the ones I did on Matlab. Can someone explain this to me? I'm new to scalogram and Python.
Here's my code and plots:

```python
data = dataset["Bearing2_2"]
a=data[:,0,790]    
sca_y_width = 500  
widths = np.arange(1, sca_y_width)
cwtmatr, freqs = pywt.cwt(a, widths, 'morl')
cwtmatr = (cwtmatr - np.min(cwtmatr))/np.ptp(cwtmatr)
plt.pcolormesh(cwtmatr)
plt.show()
```

[scalogram_python_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5cEI.jpg)

And here's what I got from Matlab
[Matlab_scalogram_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EaLf.png)

What I expected was to use CNN to learn the patterns(features) shown in Matlab scalogram plots, but by using python, it doesn't give me a good feature map.

All my data was from PRONOSTIA dataset. The specific plot was done by using Bearing2_2, acc file#790 with channel 1

Comment: The Matlab image has the vertical axis in logarithmic scale. The Python one doesn't seem to: could that explain some of the differences?. Also, it doesn't label that axis properly

Comment: What does the y-axis on Python suppose to mean? It's just the number I set for width, can I change it to Frequencies?